# image offcenter in Lightbox2

Tags: image, position, lightbox2

I am working on a new site and have used lightbox earlier. Now I changed to lightbox2 because it should work better in skeleton responsive framework which I am using. I manage to get the lightbox to work as predicted except that in left and up of the image appear white stripe, as if the image was slightly offcenter.

anyone else had this?

http://cl.ly/image/35220Z2Z093Z

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either the img has margin or it's container has padding set to non-zero. If you post a link to the page, where this bug is, it will be much easier to see where the problem is.